# Android not freeing Bitmap from memory

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have done following things to handle my bitmaps in application:

1. `LruCache` for `Bitmaps` with size of 1/8 of memory
2. Using `BitmapFactory.Options` to calculate inSampleSize
3. Catching `OOM` when creating `Bitmaps`, calling `evictAll` and `System.gc()` there
4. Also there are `AsyncTask` decoding sometimes for `Bitmaps`

I use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` and it looks like VM is not freeing `Bitmaps` fast enough from memory. I read somewhere that there might be bug using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` so I tried to use `BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor`, but there I randomly get following:

skia --- decoder->decode returned false

So is there something wrong with `FileInputStream` needed to fix here if I wan't to use `BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor` or something else to do.

This has taken me too much time and I've read all solutions based on this and how Google advices `Bitmap` handling and I've come to dead end.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with `Bitmaps`? If you ask this question, I'm sure you load'm alot

Comment: I suspect you are using bitmaps in listview or gridview and it is causing OutOfMemoryError.
If this is the case You should consider WeakReferences for Bitmaps.
Can you Elaborate your scenario further

Comment: Both in ListView and GridView, also fullscreen scaled

Comment: Please have a look into this link https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader i think this may helps u.

Comment: Our company policy doesn't allow any third party libraries.

Comment: If I use WeakReferences of Bitmap on my LruCache, does garbage collector actually work better when entries are evicted and bitmap is not used anywhere?

Comment: Not even open source libraries? It's very hard to build good apps without any third party code.

Comment: I'm designing something similar. How did you catch the OOM errors? I'm using the function I posted in my question here:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512276/android-reliable-way-to-get-percentage-of-heap-size-occupied 

but doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `SoftRefences` with `Bitmap` here. Now I can see GC freeing my unused `Bitmaps` all the time when fast scrolling `GridView` which draws them.

Tested setting my `LruCache` size full memory size and still didn't get OOM.

Penalty using this method is not that visible, my `GridView` scrolls pretty smoothly considering it's drawing very custom image.

Comment: One should always use SoftReferences or else gc still thinks the bitmap is still in use as its reference is being currently held by something in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Using large Bitmap always there is a chance to get Out Of Memory Exception..
So to handle go through Android blog

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

And always recycle the Bimap

```
ImageView mImage;
Drawable toRecycle = mImage.getDrawable();
        if ( toRecycle != null && toRecycle instanceof BitmapDrawable ) {
            if ( ( (BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable() ).getBitmap() != null )
                ( (BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable() ).getBitmap().recycle();
        }
```

Comment: This looks pretty nasty way, shouldn't platform automatically recycle that bitmap when it's not used anywhere?

Comment: Also all my Bitmap's are in LruCache so I'm looking for answer more universal where bitmap recycling happens in one place, not single solution based on one ImageView's bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() won't help you and doesn't guarantee anything.

If you absolutely sure, that evicted bitmaps are no longer needed and there is no reference to them anywhere (will catch "Can't draw recycled bitmap" exception otherwise) I would suggest you to add an EvictionListener to your LRU cache and call bitmap.recycle() on every evicted value.

Can't remember if default LRU cache provides convenience methods for setting eviction listener, but if not, it's extremely easy to extend it and add required functionality.

P.S. I would advice against WeakReferences since you lose any control of your bitmaps and purpose of LRU. Even if you load 8 bitmaps that nicely fit in your 1/8 of memory, but screen can only display 4 of them at a time (ImageViews holding a strong references to Bitmaps) gc will clear remaining 4 as soon as possible. And I really mean ultra fast. You'll have to reload bitmap for each new row (in case of ListView) you are displaying. And every bitmap that went offscreen will have to be reloaded again.

Comment: I can override entryRemoved on LruCache, but I have no idea how to detect with 100% guarantee that Bitmap is not used somewhere and I can call recycle to it. So isn't that where WeakReference would become good option, because GC might detect it to be garbage and free memory?

Comment: Why do you think that gc can't keep up, do you get OOM?

Comment: 1/8 is a tiny amount of memory. You need to load a lot of bitmaps in a short period of time to overflow it so much, that you get an OOM

Comment: Yes I do get OOM, maybe SoftReferences for my LruCache Bitmaps could do magic for GC to understand freeing memory little bit harder?

Comment: SoftReferences behave like WeakReferences in android, so there is no point in using them.

Comment: Yeah but GC cannot free bitmaps fast enough if they are strong references, atleast using SoftReferences fixes OOM issue, but GC causes performance hit here

Comment: If recycling evicted values is not an option for you, then WeakReferences is a way out. Though writing some image heavy apps never forced me to use WeakReferences

Comment: Evicted value of LruCache doesn't mean that bitmap is not used somewhere

Comment: Well, that means List with WeakReferences is your best option, using LRU in such a case is meaningless, since your bitmaps are controlled by references and not by LRU algorithms.